# Manipulate a dynamically generated html element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem here. ¿How i can manipulate a dynamically generated html, in Jquery?

I have a function like:

```
generatesomething : function(DestinationID,data){
    result = $.DoSomething(data)
    $('#'+Destinationid).html(data);
}
```

The script, in other point, receive through ajax an array. Naturally, I will iterate the array like:

```
$.each(response, function(key, value){
    ThisHtml = '<div id="div'+key'"></div>';
    $('#MyPlaceHolderDiv').html(ThisHTML)
    //In this point, i really need to call my first function
    $.generatesomething('div'+key',data)
    //But not works!!!!
}
```

How i can manipulated the generated div using my function?

### Thanks in advance!

Edit: in a try to clarify my question, i will paste the exact functions.

I made this function. Please do not laugh at my code, I am newbie in jquery.

jQuery.fn.extend({
    /*funciones Generales*/

```
piegraph : function(GraficoDestino,tipo,arrayDatos,dato1,dato2,tooltiptemplate,labeltemplate){
    var dataPoints = [];
    $.each(arrayDatos, function(key, value){
        var temporal = {};
        temporal.label = value[dato1];
        temporal.y = parseInt(value[dato2]);
        dataPoints.push(temporal);
    });
    var opciones = {

        animationEnabled : true,
        data : [{
            type : tipo,
            startAngle : 0,
            toolTipContent : tooltiptemplate,
            indexLabel : labeltemplate,
            dataPoints : dataPoints,
        }]

    };
    $('#' + GraficoDestino).CanvasJSChart(opciones);
}
```

This function works pretty well... if i can give it the destination div to it.

In other part of my script, i have a ajax call:

```
Generadisco: function(){
    var datos = {
        "accion":"generadisco"
    };
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        url: "blahblah.php",
        data: datos,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response){

            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                esteHTML = '<div id="divdisco'+key+'"></div>                    
                $('#discosplace').append(estehtml);
                //the div is generated... but when i do...:
                $(this).piegraph('divdisco'+key,'pie', response[3],0,1, "{label} #percent%","{label} ");
                //nothing happens
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the syntax error in `$.generatesomething('div'+key',data)` a copy/paste error?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you need? Seems like you made it so much complicated.

Comment: also  syntax error here   ThisHtml = '<div id="div'+key'"></div>';
what you see in console?

Comment: does #MyPlaceHolderDiv' exist? Can you display your html here?

Comment: console.log() the data you receive from the request. Make sure your div has a specific class (if many divs) or an ID (if only one div) so that you can manipulate it with `$('thediv').on('event', function(){do something;});`

Answer (score 0):

I found some error in your code:

```
$('#MyPlaceHolderDiv').html(ThisHTML)
$.generatesomething('div'+ key ,data)
```

must to be:

```
$('#MyPlaceHolderDiv').html(ThisHTML);
$.generatesomething('div'+key',data);
```

Also try to add console.log(DestinationID) in first line of your function to see passed argument (DestinationID)

Comment: I think you meant the other way, since `$.generatesomething('div'+key',data);` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the dynamic elements after your ajax call, try using async:false.

$.ajax({
  url: "abcd.html",
  async:false
}).then(function())